# Add certain strings to the front of given lines

Tags: bash, awk

I have two input files:

input1 is the file I need to process, input1 file example:

```
efgdx
efgfx
aa
efgdx
b
efgdx
```

input2 file tells what characters need to be add to which line, for example:

```
2,abcd
4,efg
5,hij
```

So, "abcd" should be added to the front of 2nd line, "efg" should be added to the front of 4th line, ...

This is the output I want:

```
efgdx
abcdefgfx
aa
efgefgdx
hijb
efgdx
```

I tried the following code but it will add strings to every line

```
awk '!p { getline m < "input2"; split(m, a, ","); p = 1} NR == a[1] {p=0} 1 { print a[2] $0}' input1
```

output from above code:

```
abcdefgdx
abcdefgfx
efgaa
efgefgdx
hijb
hijefgdx
```

Thanks very much for your inputs!

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` one-liner should do the job

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next } { print a[FNR] $0 }' input2 input1
```

or, a better method, suggested by [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), which avoids wasting memory inside `awk` by creating unnecessary array elements:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next } FNR in a{ $0=a[FNR]$0 } 1' input2 input1
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mawk 'FNR<NR? $!_=__[FNR] $_: (__[+$_]=$NF)<_' FS='.+,' f2 f1
> ```

```
efgdx
abcdefgfx
aa
efgefgdx
hijb
efgdx
```

Comment: Why `$!_`? Wouldn't that produce the wrong output when f1 matches `.+,`?

Comment: @rowboat : if OP wanted us to cover that scenario s/he should've mentioned it